# Custom Windows 7 Start Menu Search Provider

Tags: c#, windows-7, startmenu

I'd like to write custom providers for start menu searching, but I can't seem to find where to begin.

Things I'd like to be able to do when I type in the search box on the start menu

- Type "thomas" and see "IM Thomas" (if a Pidgin/whatever-IM-client-with-API contact exists with the name match)
- Type "=1+2*3" and see "7", or "=2 gallons in ounces" and see "256"
- Anything else I can think up where I have a store of custom data results that could be launched from the start menu.  This would be especially useful for custom applications, letting our users type "order XYZ", which would search orders in the application and let the user open them from the start menu.

I'm not looking for a tool to do this for me. Rather, I'd like to find any documentation on writing custom search result providers, ideally in C#.

Comment: Holy smokes - that is an awesome idea! I've always hated the fact I had to open a browser and visit google to do things like "1 Tbsp in tsp" - hope we get some good responses from this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Windows 7 API Code Pack for .NET](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

On a related note, you can add all kinds of searches to your favourites in Windows Explorer. Check out [Windows 7 Search Federation Providers](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/742-windows-7-search-federation-providers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman's blog covers [how to create a simple search connector](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingCustomSearchProvidersToWindows7PlusAdvancedSearchTricks.aspx) by creating `.osdx` files, which are XML files that configure which URL(s) to invoke with the search terms.  He then shows how to enable those connectors from within the start menu itself by adding entries to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into SlickRun a search bar alternate/replacement.  While I dont think it can be put in the place of the actual start menu search, going to thier site and getting involved will probably get you a lot closer to where you want to go.

For all I know, the functionality you describe may already be an option.

Comment: SlickRun, FindAndRunRobot, and various other launchers support similar behavior, yes. But I'm looking to build something in, rather than replace.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [Start++](http://brandontools.com/content/StartPlusPlus.aspx), which has plug-in support (it appears to use JavaScript with Windows Scripting Host).